# Javascript change textbox value within iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to change the value of a text box within iframe.
 I have tried using GetElementById in every way i could find and nothing seems to work.

I found a alternative to iframe by using the Object data tag but it has the same problem.

My code more or less, I changed it a bit for presentation:

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <title>None</title>

 </head>
 <body>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 function changeValue() {
 var textBox = document.getElementById('userName');
 textBox = "hello!";

 }

 </script>

 <iframe id="myFrame" src="http://www.website.com"></iframe> 

 <input type="button" onclick="changeValue()" value="Submit">

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: you can't access a page in an iframe if it is on another domain. This is due to security reasons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible for security reasons.

If you had access, you would be able to load, say `facebook.com` in an iframe on your website and extract user details with JavaScript.

Comment: Very true, but there is nothing in the OP's post that suggests that the page in the iframe is not on the same domain.

Comment: Of course, but since he used `http://website.com` as url, I imagined it would be an external site.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer. I was trying to access an external domain. I tested my code on my domain and it worked. Sadly this means i have hit a brick wall in my project but at least no more blind alleys. Out of curiosity is the problem on the external domain or in javascript itself?

Comment: It's a limitation in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of

```
document
    .getElementById('myFrame')
    .contentWindow
    .document
    .getElementById('userName')
    .value='hello';
```

As the others pointed out, this will only work if the page inside the iframe is on the same domain.